# how to locate the root cause of a corrupted ext3 filesystem

Tags: fsck, ext3, badblocks

I have a 4G Compact Flash card with a 2.5G ext3 partition. The file system has become corrupted.  I am not necessarily interested in fixing the file system as identifying exactly what is corrupted in the filesystem.

Aside from knowing outright the filesystem is corrupted, when running GNOME's [Disks](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility) utility, if I select the partition and select to 'repair the filesystem', it eventually errors with: Error repairing filesystem on /dev/sdb3: Process reported exit code 1: e2fscf 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013) (udisks-error-quark,0)
I got the idea from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Identify_damaged_files) to use badblocks to try to identify bad blocks, get inode numbers, and find corrupted files. however when I run this, badblocks didn't find any badblocks (ran a few times)

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb3 -b 4096 -s
Checking blocks 0 to 622517
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

I thought this was odd, so I ran fsck, but that reported no errors either:

```
sudo e2fsck -vcck /dev/sdb3
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
/dev/sdb3: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sdb3: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

      243306 inodes used (78.16%, out of 311296)
         134 non-contiguous files (0.1%)
         121 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 2469/39/0
      583752 blocks used (93.77%, out of 622518)
           0 bad blocks
           0 large files

      210273 regular files
       28804 directories
         638 character device files
          12 block device files
           1 fifo
        2646 links
        3569 symbolic links (3480 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
      245943 files
```

Now I am confused.  what does it mean that I cannot repair the filesystem, yet filesystem checker and badblocks tell me nothing is wrong. Is it just a mechanically failed CF card then? Anticlimactic...It is new after all.

Comment: You should never run a read write test on an SSD.  It just wears it out.  Instead of doing all that, use tools like smartctl to check the ssd's internal idea of its health.  I'm not sure badblocks is useful on SSDs either.

Comment: I'd only use badblocks on a spinning disk if I didn't care about any data on it and I wanted to stress test every block.  I'd never use it on an SSD.

Comment: all good comments, thanks. Any further thoughts?  I have a system that auto runs fsck after ~20 boots without having run it.  recently, this fsck once run, fails to repair the flash card and the system then fails to boot until it is wiped and the OS reinstalled. It has me scratching my head as this happens with multiple flash cards (though all same brand). Could fsck be causing the corruption? mind, it is likely an old version of fsck... the OS is a 2006 version of Gentoo

Comment: fsck can't cause corruption unless there is an underlying hardware issue.   It also doesn't (by default) test the drive, and I wouldn't recommend enabling that..  Most likely fsck is finding corruption caused by improper shutdowns.  If you pasted some of the messages from the failed fsck, we might be able to tell you what could have caused that.

Comment: Note that a read write test can wear out an SSD pretty quickly and cause it to fail.